# Sublime Text regex not detecting multiline tags

Tags: regex, tags, sublimetext

I have this regex here;

```
\[sometag\](.*)\[/sometag\]
```

Which is supposed to catch text surrounded by the `[sometag]` tag. It works for single line information contained in these tags, like on the string `[sometag]this is a bit of text[/sometag]`. But it doesn't work on text that spans multiple lines, like this;

```
[sometag] here is more text

it spans more than one line [/sometag]
```

For some reason, Sublime text's regex finder won't recognize the tags across multiple lines. I want to know if this a problem with Sublime Text, a toggleable option, or just my personal incompetence with regexes.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

At the start, use a dotall modifier `(?s)` to make dot to match also newline characters.

```
(?s)\[sometag\](.*?)\[\/sometag\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gI0xC3/1)

Comment: Thanks! Why do I have to include those extra question marks though?

Comment: `?` after `*` will do a non-greedy match. Consider `[b]foo[/b]foo[b]bar[/b]` as example. `\[b\].*\[\/b\]` would match the whole from the starting b to the last closing b.

Comment: just play with adding and removing the `?` in this http://regex101.com/r/gI0xC3/2

Comment: (?s) causes the dot to also include newlines

Comment: thansk god you exist. Ive always tried to do that in sublime but I could not because I though we could not use modifiers in sublime search/replace

Answer (score 22):

If modifying of dot's mode is inadmissible for some reasons, you may take that:

```
[sometag](.|\n)+?[/sometag]
```

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)+?` if you have an access to the DOTALL modifier. If you cannot use `(?s)` in some falvor, use `[\s\S]`/`[\d\D]`/`[\w\W]`, but not the alternation patter suggested here. This pattern is highly inefficient and can easily lead to a timeout issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Can you explain why it is inefficient? I always use `[\s\S]`, but at a glance `(.|\n)` would seem equivalent? Is it to do with matching groups? But then `(?:.|\n)` would be the same?